# Discord.py delay time send

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I was wondering with this delay string of code is there anyway to send the message to users saying how long the delay they are going to wait is?

@commands.cooldown(rate=1, per=5, type=commands.BucketType.user)

Answer (score 0):

yes we can send msg regarding how much time is left in cooldown like i have done below :

```py
@command_name.error
async def command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        em = discord.Embed(title=f"command is on cooldown",description=f"Try again in {error.retry_after:.2f}s.", color=0xFFFF00)
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Comment: I tried putting it into my code but it gave me an error at the @command_name.error part, any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Did you replace command_name by the name of your command? @DLG

Comment: Nope, just did, fixed the problem.

Comment: can u tell me how did u did it?